# PostGIS - Detect polygon groups where edges are not lined up

Tags: php, postgresql, gis, polygon, postgis

I'm trying to write a script that will detect pre grouped polygons that do not line up next to each other.  There are too major issues I'm trying to work out.  There are some polygon groups that have expected gaps (due to geographic features such as a lake)  and some polygons connect partially, so I cannot just look for where polygons do not intersect at all.  The below image is an example of worst case scenario were the union'd group has a gap on the top that cant even be read as an anti polygon as it is not closed, not to mention the large circle area is fine.

The end goal is to detect groups that have slivers like that.  Looking for suggestions on how to go about this.

Edit: The "open" slivers are whats really throwing me the wrench.  If i can possibly close the slivers by connecting the corners it would make life easier.

[image: Polygon Gap]